# How to manage a shared single session for an external website in FastAPI?

Tags: python, multithreading, fastapi

I'm building a FastAPI application that needs to obtain data from an external website. To do this, I need to manage a session with the website. However, the session will time out after some time, so I need to call `login()` again to refresh it. I want to have only one active session at a time for the whole FastAPI application.

I've managed to create a solution that seems to work, but I'm not sure if it's the best approach. Here's what I have so far:

```py
class OldAppSession:
    def __init__(self, email, password):
        self.email = email
        self.password = password
        self.session = requests.Session()
        self.login_lock = threading.Lock()
        self.login_in_progress = False
        self.login()

    def login(self) -> bool:
        """Obtain a session cookie for the old app

        Returns:
            bool: True if the login was successful, False if the login is already in progress
        """
        with self.login_lock:
            if self.login_in_progress:
                return False
            self.login_in_progress = True

            # Here I refresh my session.....

    def _request(self, method, url, data=None):
        response = getattr(self.session, method)(url, data=data)
        if response.status_code in [401, 302]:  # Unauthorized
            not_in_progress = self.login()
            if not_in_progress:
                return getattr(self.session, method)(url, data=data)
            else:
                # Sleep for a bit to give the other thread a chance to finish logging in
                for _ in range(2):
                    time.sleep(2)
                    response = getattr(self.session, method)(url, data=data)
                    if response.status_code not in [401, 302]:
                        return response
                logger.error("Failed to log in to the old app - Failed to refresh session")
                raise HTTPException(
                    status_code=status.HTTP_503_SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE,
                    detail="Failed to log in to the old app",
                )

    def get(self, url):
        return self._request("get", url)

    def post(self, url, data):
        return self._request("post", url, data=data)

old_app_session = OldAppSession("test@example.com", "12345")
```

I'm using a threading.Lock() to ensure that only one thread is logging in at a time. However, I'm not sure if this will work if I use multiple gunicorn workers. Is there a better way to manage the session that will work with multiple workers? Is there anything else I should be doing to ensure that my solution is correct?

Comment: This question may be a bit too broad for SO, but I can give some pointers. The main limitation is that you only want to have a single session with the external service and gunicorn by default is multiprocessed. If you were fine with a session per process, this solution would work fine. If the external service uses cookies for session tracking, you could implement a way to exchange the cookies between the processes with e.g. a shared database. cont...

Comment: ... Imo. the simplest solution implementation wise would be a small local to the instance single-threaded service which handles auth and proxies the requests through. This could be done with a small FastAPI service or some IPC mechanism for the web workers to talk to it. Just make sure that only the web-workers have access to this service (i.e. fixed API Key / only listening for local connections)

Comment: This might be suited for https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at your authentication model, why do not use JWT Authentication system (or others like ?)

Here is some doc about how to :
https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/security/oauth2-jwt/
https://supertokens.com/blog/what-is-jwt

With this type of authentication the user keep a token with his ID for you and the token signature prevent from token spoofing.
As this you will not have to take care of thread or things like that.

Comment: The page I am scraping does not have an API or JWT. And If I would use JWT, how can I keep only one refresh token active? When The access token becomes inactive and there are two requests at the same time, that are using the token, wouldn't I try to refresh the token twice?